# SharePoint 2013 site is not opening in Android Mobile

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, credentials, mobile-view

I am having site in SharePoint 2013, it is working fine in all browser.

but when I access it on android mobile. it keeps me **asking for credential** again and again!!!

There is **no anonymous access**.

Please help!!

Comment: I am facing the same problem, any update?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps.

1. Activate Mobile View.
2. Activate Minimal Download Feature.
3. Try request desktop site option on chrome browser.
4. Try to accessing http://sharepointURL/_layouts/mobile/mblwiki.aspx and make sure you have permission.